# Javascript switch case keeps skipping to the default case

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

My Switch case keeps on going to default.

The condition is from the intersectionWord which outputs a specific keyword from an array which matches up to a word in the trigger word array aka an intersectionWord.

```
const TriggerWord = ["weather", "add", "multiply", "divide", "subtract", "hi", "hello",];
const intersectionWord = TriggerWord.filter(element => request.requestContent.includes(element));
```

And the objective was to pass that trigger word into the switch statement to evaluate if any of those cases match up. If they do match up it should output an alert. But currently it just seems to go straight to the default case every time.

I don't know where it is going wrong.

```
 switch (intersectionWord) {
        case TriggerWord[0].toString:
            alert("Checking the weather");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[1].toString:
            alert("Doing the math");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[2].toString:
            alert("Doing multiplication");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[3].toString:
            alert("Doing the division");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[4].toString:
            alert("Doing the subtraction");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[5].toString:
            alert("Just saying Hello");
            break;
        case TriggerWord[6].toString:
            alert("Just saying Hello");
            break;

        default:
            alert("I couldn't find a TriggerWord");
    }
```

Comment: `toString` is a function. You need to call it with `()`.

Comment: Why the `.toString`? 1) The content of each item of your array is already a string (so you don't really need to stringify it again), and 2) to call a function you must put `()` after it, otherwise you're just referencing it

Comment: even with the `.toString` fixed to call the functoin, this still won't work as you're testing an array (`intersectionWord`) against a string

Comment: Consider using [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check which of the trigger words it matches, rather than a verbose `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there are two problems with your code:

- You're missing the `()` after `.toString` so it will call the function; also, it's not necessary to use `.toString()`, since they're already strings.
- `intersectionWord` is an array, so it will never be equal to any of the strings in `TriggerWords`.

Instead of the `switch/case` statement, consider using an object:

```
const messages = {
    weather: "Checking the weather",
    add: "Doing the math",
    multiply: "Doing multiplication",
    ...
}
```

Then you can loop over `intersectionWords`, looking up the corresponding message:

```
intersectionWords.forEach(word => alert(messages[word]))
```

Or you could combine them all into a single message:

```
let actions = intersectionWords.map(word => messages[word]).join(", ");
if (actions) {
    alert(actions);
} else {
    alert("No matching activity");
}
```